# awk: how to execute a command and read its output

Tags: awk

I would like to read data from stdin and execute a shell command for each parsed line and recover its output.

Here an example which almost works:

```
[root@eulbi002] # ping eulbi001 | awk -F'[ =]' '/64 bytes/{"date +%s"|getline D; print D,$11}'
1360069298 0.056
1360069298 0.051
1360069298 0.051
```

The command 'date +%s' is executed and I can recover the output, but it looks to me like the execution happens only once, not on every match.

The ultimate aim is to hand the output over to rrdtool for storage and rrdtool wants a timestamp for each record.

@Ed Morton, in addition to point out a working solution, mentioned gawk with its built-in time functions. This is the most elegant solution.

```
[root@eulbi002] # ping eulbi001 | awk -F'[ =]' '/64 bytes/{print systime(),$11}'
1360069298 0.056
1360069298 0.051
1360069298 0.051
```

Comment: date is being called for every line, but all of the output is being parsed within 1 second.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand your comment. If date is executed for every line, then I should see the variable D increase too.

Comment: Not if every time you call date it's within the same second as the last time you called date. You're telling date to print the number of seconds since the epoch so D will only change every second, not every time you call date..

Comment: The ping gets me a new line every second, so the date should run every second too, which not the case in my test above.
That is the sole reason I bring this up here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just in case there's yet another getline caveat kicking in here (see http://awk.info/?tip/getline), try closing the pipe after every invocation, e.g.:

```
ping eulbi001 |
awk -F'[ =]' 'BEGIN{cmd="date +%s"} /64 bytes/{cmd|getline D; close(cmd); print D,$11}'
```

and see if you get different results. You still shouldn't expect D to change on every invocation though, just every second. You could add a ".%N" for smaller granularity of your timestamps if you like.

Better yet, use GNU awk with it's builtin time functions so you don't need to deal with this stuff at all.