# how to convert GMT to IST using awk command

Tags: bash, awk

In nginx access.log we have time format in GMT timezone. using awk command,converting logs to csv file.

```
awk '{print $4","$7,"$10","$15","$16","$17}' </usr/local/nginx/logs/access.log>access.csv
```

$4 - displays date in GMT (31/Jul/2015:16:03:07).

Kindly guide how to change it to IST and update in that csv file.

Comment: Practice in the shell with a command like `date -f "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S" "31/Jul/2015:16:03:07"` till you get what you want, then read Ed's answer showing how to collect the output of a command in `awk` here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/14710995/2836621

Comment: And don't hard-code the OFS each time you use it, just set it once: `awk -v OFS=',' '{print $4, $7, $10, $15, $16, $17}'`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to GNU awk and GNU date, [you could use TZ](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-tz-environment-variable/) to easily get time at IST:

```
$ TZ='Asia/Kolkata' date -d "@1438374787"
```

Where the '1438374787' value is the seconds since epoch in GMT, also known as systime.

To make a systime out of a date, we could use [mktime](http://www.theunixschool.com/2013/01/gawk-date-and-time-calculation-functions.html) from (GNU) awk:

Convert the GMT string to epoch time directly in awk:

```
$ echo "a test date 31/07/2015:16:33:07" | awk '{gsub("[/:]"," ",$4); $0=$0;t=sprintf("%d %d %d %d %d %d 0",$6,$5,$4,$7,$8,$9);print(mktime(t))}'
```

For that to work, you need all values to be numbers (no jul, sorry). If that is not possible, you need to work out a format for an string that the command date could read correctly (sometimes not an easy task).

Placing all in one script:

```
#!/bin/bash --
echo "a test date 31/07/2015:16:33:07" | awk '{
    split($4,A,"[:/]");
    gmtdate=sprintf("%d %d %d %d %d %d",A[3],A[2],A[1],A[4],A[5],A[6]);
    print gmtdate;
    T1=mktime(gmtdate);
    print T1;
    pt = sprintf ("TZ=%s%s%s date -d %s%s%s%s","\047","Asia/Kolkata","\047","\042","@",T1,"\042");
    print pt;
    system(pt);
}'
```

And, running it:

```
$ ./stackoverflow-awk-time-test.sh
2015 7 31 16 33 7
1438374787
TZ='Asia/Kolkata' date -d "@1438374787"
Sat Aug  1 02:03:07 IST 2015
```

Several additional debug values are printed from awk (easy to remove).